# Text to left and image to right within same tag

Tags: html, css, liquid

I'm having some troubles aligning a piece of text along with an image that should be ( my guess ) within the same tag.

It is supossed to look like this: [image: How it should look] (Ignore the black stripe)

but it is currently looking like this: [image: How it currently looks]

The HTML for it is:

```
<span class="size-chart-disclaimer">If in doubt, measure your similar<br>
 style garment and match our grid. 
<img src="{{'we-use.gif' | asset_url}}"/></span>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.size-chart-disclaimer img{
float:right;
}
```

Could someone shed a light on the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you mind putting the text in another tag?

Comment: @MaihanNijat I could do that! Any pointers on the best way ?

Comment: I created an example for you in the answer. check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a tag for the text, and then style it.

```css
.size-chart-disclaimer img {
  float: right;
}
p {
  width: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<span class="size-chart-disclaimer">
  <p>
  If in doubt, measure your similar
  style garment and match our grid. 
  </p>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50"/>
</span>
```

Comment: Just had to add the line-height property but this worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just placing the image in front of the text does the job aswell:

```css
.size-chart-disclaimer img{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span class="size-chart-disclaimer">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50" /> If in doubt, measure your similar
    <br /> style garment and match our grid.
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css to yout `img` tag: `vertical-align: middle;`

See this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64jdg1zm/1/)**